# How to validate parameter input in dialogflow

Tags: javascript, validation, google-calendar-api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to validate parameter entered by user before i continue with  booking .

Here is my code :

```
function makeAppointment (agent) {
        // Use the Dialogflow's date and time parameters to create Javascript Date instances, 'dateTimeStart' and 'dateTimeEnd',
        // which are used to specify the appointment's time.
        const appointmentDuration = 1;// Define the length of the appointment to be one hour.

        const dateTimeStart = convertParametersDate(agent.parameters.date, agent.parameters.time,timeZoneOffset);
        const dateTimeEnd = addHours(dateTimeStart, appointmentDuration);
        const appointmentTimeString = getLocaleTimeString(dateTimeStart);
        const appointmentDateString = getLocaleDateString(dateTimeStart);
        // Check the availability of the time slot and set up an appointment if the time slot is available on the calendar
        return createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd).then(() => {
            agent.add(`Done `);
        }).catch(() => {
            agent.add(` Sorry check other date`);
        });
    }
    function createCalendarEvent (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            calendar.events.list({  // List all events in the specified time period
                auth: serviceAccountAuth,
                calendarId: calendarId,
                timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
                timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
            }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
                // Check if there exists any event on the calendar given the specified the time period
                if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
                    reject(err || new Error('Die angeforderte Zeit kollidiert mit einem anderen Termin'));
                } else {
                    // Create an event for the requested time period
                    calendar.events.insert({ auth: serviceAccountAuth,
                            calendarId: calendarId,
                            resource: {summary: 'Appointment',
                                start: {dateTime: dateTimeStart},
                                end: {dateTime: dateTimeEnd}}
                        }, (err, event) => {
                            err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

My validation should be : if dateTimeStart < now  then agent will responde you can't book a date passed
or is dateTimeStart < openhourtime ( time when service can be provide) and dateTimeEnd > closehourtime

openhourtime = '09:00'
closehourtime = '16:00'

Can you help me how to make this inside code?

Comment: Does the function 'convertParametersDate' return you a date object or a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use the [Google sample code](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook) where the helper function Implement your if statement within the function `convertParametersDate` returns you a date object, you can modify your function `makeAppointment` as following to implement date validation:

```
function makeAppointment (agent) {
        // Use the Dialogflow's date and time parameters to create Javascript Date instances, 'dateTimeStart' and 'dateTimeEnd',
        // which are used to specify the appointment's time.
        const appointmentDuration = 1;// Define the length of the appointment to be one hour.

        const dateTimeStart = convertParametersDate(agent.parameters.date, agent.parameters.time,timeZoneOffset);
        const dateTimeEnd = addHours(dateTimeStart, appointmentDuration);
        const appointmentTimeString = getLocaleTimeString(dateTimeStart);
        const appointmentDateString = getLocaleDateString(dateTimeStart);
        // Check the availability of the time slot and set up an appointment if the time slot is available on the calendar

       //here the new part:
        var now = new Date();
        var openhour = 9;
        var closehour = 16;
        if (dateTimeStart.getTime() < now.getTime() || dateTimeStart.getHours() < openhour || dateTimeEnd.getHours()> closehour){
          agent.add(` Sorry check other date`);
        } else {
        return createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd).then(() => {
            agent.add(`Done `);
        }).catch(() => {
            agent.add(` Sorry check other date`);
        });
      }
    }
```

The methods used for the implementation of the validation are Javascript Date Object methods, specifically [getTime()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp), [getHours()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp) and [new Date()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).